EF Bulk Extensions is really slow for me, but why?
I have a C# console app on .NET 6.0, using EF Core 6.0.35.
I am making an API call to get data (from Geotab) that I filter, transform and insert into my DB. Each insert is 1000 to 2000 records.
My table in SQL Server 2022 (v16.0.1135.2) looks like this:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DiagnosticData]
(
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DeviceId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DiagnosticId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [float] NOT NULL,
    [DateTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [UpdateDateTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL 
)

Corresponding model class:
public class DiagnosticData 
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int64? Id { get; set; }
    [Column("DeviceId")]
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    [Column("DiagnosticId")]
    public int DiagnosticId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Double Value { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime UpdateDateTime {  get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
}

I have tried the following three methods of inserting data:
ONE: Basic EF Core code:
public static async Task BulkInsertAsyncEF(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
{
    await using (PCContext _context = new PCContext())
    {
        _context.AddRangeAsync(entities);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}

TWO: (not my preferred method, but more as an experiment to test execution time)
public static async Task BulkInsertSqlAsync(IEnumerable<DiagnosticData> diagnosticData)
{
    await using (PCContext _context = new PCContext())
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (DiagnosticData dd in diagnosticData)
        {
            sb.Append("INSERT INTO DiagnosticData (DeviceId, DiagnosticId, Value, DateTime, UpdateDateTime) values (");
            sb.Append(dd.DeviceId);
            sb.Append(',');
            sb.Append(dd.DiagnosticId);
            sb.Append(',');
            sb.Append(dd.Value);
            sb.Append(",'");
            sb.Append(dd.DateTime.ToString());
            sb.AppendLine("',getdate());");
        }
        await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(sb.ToString());
    }
}

THREE: Entity Framework Bulk Extensions
public static async Task BulkInsertAsync(IEnumerable<DiagnosticData> entities)
{
    await using (PCContext _context = new PCContext())
    {
        using var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction();
        await _context.BulkInsertAsync(entities, options => { options.IncludeGraph = false; options.PreserveInsertOrder = false; }); 
        transaction.Commit();
    }
}

They're executed as follows:
IEnumerable<PC.DiagnosticData> diagnosticData = new List<PC.DiagnosticData>();
diagnosticData = statusData.Select(sd => new PC.DiagnosticData()
{
    DateTime = sd.DateTime.Value,
    DeviceId = devices.First(dv => dv.DeviceId == sd.Device.Id.ToString()).Id,  
    DiagnosticId = diagnostics.FirstOrDefault(di => di.DiagnosticId == sd.Diagnostic.ToString()).Id,
    Value = sd.Data.Value
}
);

// await PC.DiagnosticData.BulkInsertSqlAsync(diagnosticData);
await PC.DiagnosticData.BulkInsertAsync(diagnosticData);
// await PC.DiagnosticData.BulkInsertAsyncEF(diagnosticData);

statusData holds the response from the Geotab API

Method one takes 10 to 15 seconds to insert ~1000 records, which is way too slow according to my gut instinct (and this page).
Method two was faster at ~2 seconds for ~1000 records (still too slow!)
Method three was about the same as method one.

None of the records will EVER exist in the DB already, so an update will never be necessary.
I have tried on two separate instances of SQL Server and got the same results (one is my local dev machine with no other traffic)
Considering that methods one and three take roughly the same amount of time suggests that it's an issue at the EF level, but what?

Try without transaction.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv I have and there is no difference

The insertion code in the EF Code returns the IDs of the inserted entities. This is one of the reasons for its slower operation. In your method Two, you don't do that. Unfortunately, at EF we can't give up on this.

Consider upgrading to a newer version. Read, for example, about the improvements in EF7. Inserting multiple rows can be four times faster than on EF Core 6.0!

What is the performance you get if you use BulkInsert instead of BulkInsertAsync?

devices.First... and diagnostics.FirstOrDefault... looks suspicious. Maybe that harmed performance?

@SvyatoslavDanyliv That part of the code is perfectly quick. Is it optimal? Maybe not. It's ONLY the insert that is slow

@mjwills There is no appreciable difference

Give our extension, linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore, a try! Not sure that I will help if you have hidden issues with database.

If you are looking to do bulk inserts with the shortest processing time, you need to use the Bulk Copy operations that are included for the System.Data.SqlClient namespace.  Entity Framework is going to build individual insert statements because it's not designed to utilize many native approaches.  Individual insert statements will always take more time.
You will need to employ the class called SqlBulkCopy.  The approach will be speedy, but the obvious tradeoff is that the code you write will be specific to SQL Server and won't translate to other DBMS systems as Entity Framework is designed to do.
One important detail - you can inject data from a DataTable or a DataReader.  The DataTable is RAM-based, whereas the DataReader is from a database-connected source.
Read more here.

See my note about DataTable vs DataReader.

Thanks. I was actually planning on building a stripped down version of the app without EF and just using ADO.Net and SqlBulkCopy, but your answer doesn't explain why these operations are taking so much longer than expected. My manually generated INSERTs was 5x faster than the EF Bulk Extensions, which is supposed to be only marginally slower than SqlBulkCopy

@AdamHey You are building ONE large SQL statement.  EF isn't doing the same, it is sending an insert statement for each row.  There is associated overhead each time EF sends a statement, waits for a result, and then sends the next -- on the server side, each individual statement also has to be parsed and compiled before execution.  A single statement won't have as much overhead.

EF isn't doing the same, it is sending an insert statement for each row. That isn't what option 3 is doing.

I know they are all fundamentally different in terms of execution. That's why I tried the three different approaches to compare execution time. My comparison was only in terms of execution time.  @Xavier The "vanilla" EF command generates a MERGE for each record, not an INSERT

@XavierJ, BulkInsertAsync should utilize BulkCopy. The OP mentioned using several methods to achieve this, so I'm unclear on the purpose or relevance of your response.
